# Add a sequence column in a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query like below

```
select ref_leger_code,rate,sum(balance),to_char(due_date,'yyyymm')
from tbl_value_temp
group by ref_leger_code,rate,to_char(due_date,'yyyymm');
```

and the output is:
[image: output]

but I want to change the query that give me the output like below:
[image: output2]

Comment: What determines the sequence reset? 'rate` alone? Or `rate_ledger_code, rate`? Or something else? Please provide us with the business rules you want to implement instead of expecting us to reverse engineer them from your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are looking about numbering the rows based on the `rate` so use an analytic function like this :

```
 select ref_leger_code, rate, sumbalance, due_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rate ORDER BY due_date asc ) AS sequence  
 from   (
          select ref_leger_code, rate, sum(balance) sumbalance, to_char(due_date,'yyyymm') due_date
          from   tbl_value_temp
          group by ref_leger_code, rate, to_char(due_date,'yyyymm')
        );
```

Comment: It gives error: ORA-00924: missing BY keyword
00924. 00000 -  "missing BY keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 35

Comment: @navidsedigh - Dypso missed the BY after the PARTITION keyword. I have corrected their code, please try it now.